# Get value from Directive into Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

So I have this filter directive:

```angular
app.directive('filter', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        callFunc: '&'
    },
    template:
            '   <div>' +
            '       <div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '   </div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        this.getData = function() {
            $scope.callFunc()
        }
    }
  }   
});

app.directive('positions', function(){
  return {
    require: '^filter', 
    scope: {
        selectedPos: '='
    },
    template:
            '  Positions: {{selectedPos}}' +
            '  <ul>' +
            '   <li ng-repeat="pos in positions">' +
            '           <a href="#" ng-click="setPosition(pos); posRegData()">{{pos.name}}</a></a>' +
            '       </li>' +
            '  </ul>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
          $scope.positions = [
            {name: '1'},
            {name: '2'},
            {name: '3'},
            {name: '4'},
            {name: '5'}
          ];
          $scope.selectedPos = $scope.positions[0].name;
          $scope.setPosition = function(pos){
            $scope.selectedPos = pos.name;
          };

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, filterCtrl) {
        scope.posRegData = function() {
            filterCtrl.getData();
        }
    }
  }   
})
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('keyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var key = this;
  key.callFunc = function() {
    key.value = key.selectedPos;
    console.log(key.selectedPos)
  }
}]);
```

The main question is why the `key.selectedPos` in the controller get's the right value only on the second click?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Cp4rsqEh6FJao6PowNq?p=preview) replicating my issue.

Comment: can you use isolated scope and pass selectedPos as a parameter?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because selectedPos is actually the selected item inside a dropdown

Comment: why? you can use two-way binding though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a param when you call your `callFunc()`.

Update your func in the ctrl: `key.callFunc = function(filterParams)`, also don't forget to update you passed method `call-func="key.callFunc(filterParams)`

In `filter directive` change your getData method to:

```
this.getData = function(val) {
  $scope.callFunc({filterParams: val})
}
```

In `positions directive` pass the value that you need:

```
scope.posRegData = function() {
  filterCtrl.getData({position: scope.selectedPos});
}
```

Now in your `keyCtrl` you can get the value:

```
key.callFunc = function(filterParams) {
  key.value = filterParams.position;
  console.log(filterPrams.position)
}
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibWobKiYXMMdzFwl0dJS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $broadcast on the $rootScope

in your controller do:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', $scope.selectedPos);
```

in your target controller you then have a listener:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, myData){...})
```

[angularJS documentation $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

and a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8IkbWrOHHiq4HDBNVyCP?p=preview)

Comment: I am trying to avoid using $broadcasts and other similar methods

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I think an isolated scope works:

```
app.directive('positions', function(){
  return {
    require: '^filter',
    scope : {
      selectedPos: '='
    },
    template:
        '<button dropdown>' +
        '    {{selectedPos}}' +
        '  <ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
        '    <li ng-repeat="pos in positions">' +
        '      <a href="#" ng-click="setPosition(pos)">{{pos.name}}</a></a>' +
        '    </li>' +
        '  </ul>' +
        '</button>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
          $scope.setPosition = function(pos){
            $scope.selectedPos = pos.name;
          };
          $scope.positions = [
            {name: '1'},
            {name: '2'},
            {name: '3'}
          ];
          $scope.selectedPos = $scope.positions[0].name;
    }
  }   
});
```

See:http://plnkr.co/edit/boKjmMmsCCZem0lETT3B?p=preview

Comment: Strange. I wonder if that is a plunker issue or a Angular issue

Comment: take a look at my plunker